# Missing schema module for spring-cloud-stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

Trying to use the following [example from Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_converters_with_schema_support)

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter userMessageConverter() throws IOException {
  AvroSchemaMessageConverter avroSchemaMessageConverter {
  return new AvroSchemaMessageConverter(MimeType.valueOf("avro/bytes");
}
```

Using Gradle as follows

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream')
  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka')
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR2"
  }
}
```

Gradle is loading the correct version of spring-cloud-streams `1.1.0.RELEASE` but it does not match with the [Github Repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/releases/tag/v1.1.0.RELEASE). The artifact is missing the `org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema` package/source.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifact `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka` brings in `spring-cloud-stream`, `spring-cloud-stream-codec` and related dependencies like `spring-integration`. You would have to explicitly define `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-schema`.

Also, you don't need to specify 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream' as it will be part of `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka` via `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka`.