# Missing AvroSchemaMessageConverter class in spring-cloud-stream-schema - 1.2.0.RC1

Tags: maven, avro, spring-cloud-stream, jackson-dataformat-avro

I am missing AvroSchemaMessageConverter class in spring-cloud-stream-schema - 1.2.0.RC1. I want through this link [Missing schema module for spring-cloud-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813184/missing-schema-module-for-spring-cloud-stream).

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-schema</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RC1</version>
  </dependency>
```

When I looked at the [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-schema/pom.xml), I was anticipating the class [AvroSchemaMessageConverter.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-schema/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/schema/avro/AvroSchemaMessageConverter.java) will be available in **spring-cloud-stream-1.2.0.RC1.jar**. But it does not exist as per the picture below:

[image: Eclipse Spring dependencies]

**Can someone point to the dependency I am missing.** My maven dependencies for spring-cloud-stream to post to Kafka topics.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.RC1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache avro serialization support  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-schema</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the schema jar:

```
<!-- Apache avro serialization support  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-schema</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Notice the full hierarchy of that GitHub Artifact...

```
spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream-schema/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/schema/avro/AvroSchemaMessageConverter.java
```

Comment: My mistake. I am now looking at my eclipse IDE and don't see that jar. I now updated my maven project and again looked up the jar. Now I see that. Thanks for pointing my mistake. I need workout my string parser :-)

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted explicitly mentions that you need to include `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-schema`, where `AvroSchemaMessageConverter` lives. You will also need to add an Avro version explicitly.

Comment: Eventually I had to do that. Thank you for the advice.